# How to assert a UILabel.text property is equal to an instance of NSString in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ocunit

I'm new to objective-c and I'm finding that I don't know how to correctly assert that a text property on some given label is equal to a raw string value.  I'm not sure if I just need to cast the label as NSString or if I need to modify my assert statement directly.

```
@interface MoreTest : SenTestCase {
  MagiczzTestingViewController* controller;
}

- (void) testObj;

@end

@implementation MoreTest

- (void) setUp
{
  controller = [[MagiczzTestingViewController alloc] init];
}

- (void) tearDown
{
  [controller release];
}

- (void) testObj
{
  controller.doMagic;

  STAssertEquals(@"hehe", controller.label.text, @"should be hehe, was %d instead", valtxt);
}

@end
```

The implementation of my doMagic method is below

```
@interface MagiczzTestingViewController : UIViewController {
  IBOutlet UILabel *label;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *label;
- (void) doMagic;

@end

@implementation MagiczzTestingViewController
@synthesize label;

- (void) doMagic 
{
  label.text = @"hehe";
}

- (void)dealloc {
  [label release];
  [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

The build is fine when I modify the assert to compare a raw NSString to another but when I try to capture the text value (assuming it's of type NSString) it fails.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Note: While the end result is the same, it's idiomatically clearer to invoke your method as `[controller doMagic]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load the nib of the view controller.  Otherwise there won't be any objects for the label outlet to be hooked up to.

One way to do this is to add an ivar for the view controller's view to your test case:

```
@interface MoreTest : SenTestCase {
    MagiczzTestingViewController *controller;
    UIView *view;
}
@end

@implementation MoreTest

- (void)setUp
{
    [super setUp];

    controller = [[MagiczzTestingViewController alloc] init];
    view = controller.view; // owned by controller
}

- (void)tearDown
{
    view = nil; // owned by controller
    [controller release];

    [super tearDown];
}

- (void)testViewExists
{
    STAssertNotNil(view,
        @"The view controller should have an associated view.");
}

- (void)testObj
{
    [controller doMagic];

    STAssertEqualObjects(@"hehe", controller.label.text,
        @"The label should contain the appropriate text after magic.");
}

@end
```

Note that you also need to invoke super's `-setUp` and `-tearDown` methods appropriately from within yours.

Finally, **do not** use dot syntax for method invocation, it is not a generic replacement for bracket syntax in message expressions.  Use dot syntax **only** for getting and setting object state.

Answer (score 7):

`STAssertEquals()` checks for *identity* of the two values provided, so it's equivalent to doing this:

```
 STAssertTrue(@"hehe" == controller.label.text, ...);
```

Instead, you want `STAssertEqualObjects()`, which will actually run an `isEqual:` check like the following:

```
 STAssertTrue([@"hehe" isEqual:controller.label.text], ...);
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same output (failed test) in the console with the isEqual: syntax - anything else I'm missing when I try to test IBOutlet items?

Comment: Is the IBOutlet hooked up correctly? If it is, the only other thing that comes to mind is that unit tests tend to be glitchy when it comes to UI components. Sometimes UI components won't initialize, won't update (because they depend on a run loop, for instance), etc.